# Why "path" is used by OS & Why "classpath" is used by compiler & JVM?

Tags: java, jvm

- **PATH**: It is a normal environment variable on Windows.
- **CLASSPATH**: It contains libraries path which JVM will look for.

I found these information from internet but i am confused about why  "path" is used by OS & Why "classpath" is used by compiler & JVM?

Comment: @skip What would you have preferred instead?

Comment: `PATH` has been inherited from the good old DOS times.

Comment: @biziclop: `PATH` is a \*nix concept that predates DOS.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is, nevertheless Windows inherited it from DOS.

Answer (score 1):

Because they're entirely different things. `PATH` is for locating executables when you run them without any path information. `CLASSPATH` is for finding Java classes.

Comment: Crowder I believe the OP already knows what `CLASSPATH` is used for.